# Appium on ADF: Test upload failed using Amazon Device Farm Jenkins plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, pytest, python-appium, aws-device-farm

I'm attempting to run Py.Test on Amazon Device Farm, I got the steps to upload the App, select a device pool working.  However at the last step where it tries to upload and run the test it fails, and I don't have an idea why.  Any insights will be helpful.

The repo I'm trying to run is, https://github.com/dlai0001/appium-spike-running-tests-oncloud

Here are my Jenkins logs:

```
Copied 1 artifact from "mock-ios-build" build number 3
[AWSDeviceFarm] Using Project 'appium-poc'
[AWSDeviceFarm] Using DevicePool 'iPhone6 only'
[AWSDeviceFarm] Using App 'staging/TapIt.ipa'
[AWSDeviceFarm] Archiving artifact 'TapIt.ipa'
[AWSDeviceFarm] Uploading TapIt.ipa to S3
[AWSDeviceFarm] Waiting for upload TapIt.ipa to be ready (current status: INITIALIZED)
[AWSDeviceFarm] Upload TapIt.ipa succeeded
[AWSDeviceFarm] Getting test to schedule.
[AWSDeviceFarm] Archiving artifact 'test_examply.py'
[AWSDeviceFarm] Uploading test_examply.py to S3
[AWSDeviceFarm] Waiting for upload test_examply.py to be ready (current status: INITIALIZED)
[AWSDeviceFarm] Upload test_examply.py failed!
Build step 'Run Tests on AWS Device Farm' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Note, using the shovel task to package the zip file and uploading and running the test through the Amazon device farm web console works.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  There are 2 things going on,

First, Amazon Device Farm does not like Shovel.  I had to take out shovel from the requirements.txt.

2nd, the Jenkins plugin is expecting a packaged zip file. So create a build task that zips up all the depedencies (without shovel)

```
from shovel import task
import subprocess
import os

@task
def package():
    print("checking tests are collectable")
    result = subprocess.call("py.test --collect-only tests/", shell=True)
    if result != 0:
        print("test collection failed.")
        exit(1)

    print("generating wheelhouse dependencies.")
    result = subprocess.call("pip wheel --wheel-dir wheelhouse -r requirements.txt", shell=True)
    if result != 0:
        print("Generating wheel failed.")
        exit(1)

    print("cleaning unused files.")
    subprocess.call("find . -name '__pycache__' -type d -exec rm -r {} +", shell=True)
    subprocess.call("find . -name '*.pyc' -exec rm -f {} +", shell=True)
    subprocess.call("find . -name '*.pyo' -exec rm -f {} +", shell=True)
    subprocess.call("find . -name '*~' -exec rm -f {} +", shell=True)

    print("zipping test files.")
    result = subprocess.call("zip -r test_bundle.zip tests/ wheelhouse/ requirements.txt", shell=True)
    if result != 0:
        print("Failed to Zip files for Amazon.")
        exit(1)
```

Then configure the Jenkins ADF task it to point to the zip file.

[image: Jenkins ADF plugin]